# Using fscanf to scan fixed length ints into an array

Tags: c, scanf

How can I use `fscanf` (or any other function that deals with `stdin`s from a text file) to scan a certain group of integers, that have the same length, and put them in the same array, but at the same time ignore integers that are shorter than required

This is how the txt file looks:

```
63001234 1 1 -1 - - 0 1 1 1 - - 0
63001230 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
63001432 -1 -1 - - - - - - - - - -
63000176 - - 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

I need to store the 63... numbers in one int array and '1','-1','0' and '-' in another char array.

this is now my scan and test function in one

```
int main() {

    printf("insert the name of the txt file you want to scan from: ");
    char fileopen [100];
    scanf("%s", fileopen);

    int Students [250];
    char Grades [250] [12];

    FILE *fop = fopen(fileopen ,"r");
    if(fop == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int counter = 0;

    //read file
    while(1){
        if(fscanf(fop,"%d",&Students[counter]) == EOF){
            break;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
            fscanf(fop," %c",&Grades[counter][j]);
        }
        fscanf(fop,"\n");
        counter++;

    }

    counter = 0;
    //test what has been written in the arrays 
    while(counter <= strlen(Students)){

       printf("%d", Students[counter]);
       for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
            printf(" %c", Grades[counter][j]);
        }
        counter++;
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is, because i need these numbers by order for later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read to ints and chars directly instead of using a digit check:

```
// You can use dynamic memory allocation here instead, or an appropriate max size.
// I used 100 because this is a template.
int numbers[100];
int chars[100][12];

char* line = (char*)malloc(100);

int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    /* Read line into buffer */
    if ((fgets(line, 100, file) == NULL) || ferror(file) || feof(file))
    {
        break;
    }

    /* Skip empty lines */
    if (strcmp(line, "\n") != 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    /* Scan the integer */
    if (i == 0) {
        sscanf(line, "%d", &numbers[0]);
    } else {
        sscanf(line, "\n%d", &numbers[i]);
    }

    /* Scan the 12 characters */
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 12; ++j)
    {
        sscanf(line, " %c", &chars[i][j]);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Any other, more elegant solution?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but multiple `fscanf()`s intended to process the same physical line is a brittle approach. Use `fgets()` to read a full line at a time, then `sscanf()` to tokenize it.

Comment: I guess that could be a better solution.

Comment: @unwind Could you write this in a code, i have a hard time to write what i haven't seen an example of

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Can i add in the first for loop(instead of the condition i<4) fscanf(...) != EOF because i don't know how many 63...ints there is

Comment: Yes, I just updated the solution so it scan N lines.
Haven't implemented the `fgets` thing yet though.

Comment: @user2202368 if you're going to be a programmer, you should not be afraid to experiment on your own.  You don't learn much having SO members do it all for you.  Dive in and try it.

Comment: @Randy Howard time is not on my side

Comment: @Magtheridon96 okey, the first line scans just fine, but then it starts to putting 63... ints in char array :S

Comment: i opened it with "r" :/ i edited my question with your solution implemented

Comment: Try with "rt". If that still doesn't work, I'll update my solution to use `fgets` as unwind suggested.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Same, first line ok, then it all goes to hell

Comment: Try it now. If it still doesn't work with multiple `sscanf` calls, then you may have to revert to the non-elegant solution :c

Comment: It's even worse. Is it possible that my heck part is somehow letting out these weird signs